# How to read multiline string in Excel Cell in powershell?

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell

I'm trying to use a powershell script to read through a certain column in my excel file and do some text processing to the data in that column. Each cell in that column may/may not contain multiline data.

What I did was loop through a cell, and for each cell I've looped, I've stored the data into a here-string and then loop through that here-string to read through each line in the multi-line text.

I'm able to read all lines in cells which contain multiple line data, however when the loop reaches cells with single line data, it does not display the singleline data out and comes out as a blank. I need some assistance to identify my issue. Would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```bsh
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$xlsPath = "C:\Users\csjeemah\Documents\Jeevan\Powershell Scripts\sample.xlsx"
$workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\csjeemah\Documents\Jeevan\Powershell Scripts\sample.xlsx")
$workSheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$workSheet.activate()
$worksheet.Columns.Replace("\","/")
```

```bsh
$maxRows = (($workSheet.UsedRange.Rows).count) - 1
$sourceCol = 2
$sourceRow = 2
 for($souceRow = 1; $sourceRow -lt $maxRows; $sourceRow++){
 $sourceData = $workSheet.Cells.Item($sourceRow,$sourceCol).text
 $sourceArray = @"
$sourceData
"@ -split "`n" | % {$_.trim() }
    $lineCounter = 1
    for($src = 0; $src -le $sourceArray.count - 1 ; $src ++){
       echo $sourceArray[$src] 'this is line' $lineCounter 'in cell'
       $lineCounter = $lineCounter + 1
     }
 } 
$workbook.SaveAs($xlsPath)
$workbook.close($false)
$Excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)
Remove-Variable Excel
```

Comment: why are you putting the data into a here-string? it _should_ work just fine when assigned to a $Var without the here-string stuff.

Comment: Why don't you give a try to `Import-Excel` module ?

Comment: I tried assigning to a regular var but i can't loop through a regular var, won't it have to be stored as an array to be looped through?